# Hiding the toolbar after collapsing on Android

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I would like to have something like instagram because it's very cool! They have toolbars in their cardviews or views in the listview of them. And if one collapsed with another the upper ***toolbar goes away*** and the lower toolbar take the place of the toolbar.

I have these codes for `MainActivity` and a `Fragment` in it.

My **MainActivity** has this xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                layout="@layout/tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**In my fragment is a listview and the listview contains cardview. The cardview has the following:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dddd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullCardItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/card_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can i hide that toolbar after collapsing ?

Comment: you mean, something like this ? https://github.com/xuyisheng/DesignSupportLibraryDemo/raw/master/gif/6%E6%9C%88%2004%2C%202015%2022:57.gif after collapsed, toolbar is going to be disappeared.

Comment: yes! But the problem is that the toolbars are in different layouts or am I wrong? :D First of all thanks for the gif it is a good example

Comment: the second one is not Toolbar, it is TabLayout btw :) no those are haven't any similar id's -> `tool_bar` and second one: `android:id="@+id/card_toolbar"` on the first one it is looking for this layout : `layout="@layout/tool_bar"`

Comment: The thing is that I have a toolbar in my listview item and if I scroll down in my listview the toolbar and tablayout will disappear but the toolbar in my listview item will no take the place of a toolbar

Comment: You should check my answer for that, and of course, above codes are not enough to make a decision about that, so please add full codes.and be carefull about using those codes in `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Put what ever you want to disappeard after collapsing on `AppBarLayout`.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Live example:** https://github.com/xuyisheng/DesignSupportLibraryDemo

And of course, take a look at this:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```